# Llevar resultado de Consulta (select * from ...) a XML

Tags: oracle, stored-procedure

Queria saber si existe una manera en Oracle 10gR2, que el resultado de una consulta (`Select * from ...`) se almacenen en un XML.

Quiero que un procedimiento almacenado tenga un solo parámetro de salida (XMLType), pero la información de este parámetro varíe dinámicamente.

Por ejemplo, en una ejecución de un SP me retorne el XML correspondiente a un "`select * from TablaA`", en otra ejecución del mismo SP me retorne otro XML correspondiente a un "`select * from TablaB`", y así pueda ir haciendo variar el contenido del XML.

En resumen, ¿cómo convierto el resultado de un "`select * from ...`" a XML, y este XML retornarlo como parámetro de salida de un procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿podrías aceptar la respuesta si te ha sido de utilidad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consulta:

```
SELECT XMLElement("Emp", 
                   XMLElement("name", e.first_name ||' '|| e.last_name),
                   XMLElement("hiredate", e.hire_date)) AS "RESULT" 
FROM hr.employees e 
WHERE employee_id > 200;
```

Resultado:

```
RESULT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
<Emp><name>Michael Hartstein</name><hiredate>2004-02-17</hiredate></Emp>
<Emp><name>Pat Fay</name><hiredate>2005-08-17</hiredate></Emp>
<Emp><name>Susan Mavris</name><hiredate>2002-06-07</hiredate></Emp>
<Emp><name>Hermann Baer</name><hiredate>2002-06-07</hiredate></Emp>
<Emp><name>Shelley Higgins</name><hiredate>2002-06-07</hiredate></Emp>
<Emp><name>William Gietz</name><hiredate>2002-06-07</hiredate></Emp>

6 rows selected.
```

Consulta 2:

```
SELECT XMLElement("Emp", XMLAttributes(
                           e.employee_id as "ID",
                           e.first_name ||' ' || e.last_name AS "name"))
  AS "RESULT"
  FROM hr.employees e
  WHERE employee_id > 200;
```

Resultado:

```
RESULT
-----------------------------------------------
<Emp ID="201" name="Michael Hartstein"></Emp>
<Emp ID="202" name="Pat Fay"></Emp>
<Emp ID="203" name="Susan Mavris"></Emp>
<Emp ID="204" name="Hermann Baer"></Emp>
<Emp ID="205" name="Shelley Higgins"></Emp>
<Emp ID="206" name="William Gietz"></Emp>

6 rows selected.
```

Consulta 3:

```
SELECT XMLElement("Employee", 
                  XMLAttributes('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS
                                  "xmlns:xsi",
                                'http://www.oracle.com/Employee.xsd' AS
                                  "xsi:nonamespaceSchemaLocation"),
                  XMLForest(employee_id, last_name, salary)) AS "RESULT"
   FROM hr.employees
   WHERE department_id = 10;
```

Resultado:

```
RESULT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Employee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xsi:nonamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.oracle.com/Employee.xsd">
   <EMPLOYEE_ID>200</EMPLOYEE_ID>
   <LAST_NAME>Whalen</LAST_NAME>
   <SALARY>4400</SALARY>
</Employee>

1 row selected.
```

Consulta 4

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE emp_t AS OBJECT ("@EMPNO" NUMBER(4),
                                         ENAME VARCHAR2(10));

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE emplist_t AS TABLE OF emp_t;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE dept_t AS OBJECT ("@DEPTNO" NUMBER(2),
                                         DNAME VARCHAR2(14),
                                         EMP_LIST emplist_t);

SELECT XMLElement("Department",
                  dept_t(department_id,
                         department_name,
                         cast(MULTISET
                              (SELECT employee_id, last_name
                                 FROM hr.employees e
                                 WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id)
                              AS emplist_t)))
  AS deptxml
  FROM hr.departments d
  WHERE d.department_id = 10;
```

Resultado:

```
DEPTXML
-------------
<Department>
  <DEPT_T DEPTNO="10">
    <DNAME>ACCOUNTING</DNAME>
    <EMPLIST>
      <EMP_T EMPNO="7782">
        <ENAME>CLARK</ENAME>
      </EMP_T>
      <EMP_T EMPNO="7839">
        <ENAME>KING</ENAME>
      </EMP_T>
      <EMP_T EMPNO="7934">
        <ENAME>MILLER</ENAME>
      </EMP_T>
    </EMPLIST>
  </DEPT_T>
</Department>

1 row selected.
```

Referencia: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#ADXDB1620

Comment: Mil gracias por la respuesta, me sirvio de maravilla, pero tengo un problema, en el caso de que un campo de un registro de la consulta tenga valor null, el XML generado simplemente ya no genera el nodo para ese campo, entonces como puedo hacer para que si el campo es null si me genere el nodo (obviamente vacio <nodo></nodo>), bueno esto es porque este XML llegara a una clase en .net y debe ser deserealizado a un objeto para lo cual debe tener los nodos completos.

Comment: mil de nadas hermano :D me alegra mucho saber que te ha sido de utilidad :D Creo que el comentario es válido para formular otra pregunta. Saludos